# Upwork API Python library - ImportError: cannot import name 'client'

Tags: python, upwork-api

I have a problem when using [Python Upwork library](https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork). It has been installed through PIP.

In ...\site-packages\upwork\ I created myAuth.py file.

The content of this file is so far:

```
apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
secretKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

import upwork
```

Here's traceback from cmd line:

```
C:\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\upwork>python myAuth.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myAuth.py", line 4, in <module>
    import upwork
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\upwork\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from upwork.client import Client
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\upwork\client.py", line 8, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in
load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in
_resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _
import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\upwork\http.py", line 6, in <module>
    from compatibility import HTTPError, httplib
  File "C:\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\upwork\compatibility.py", line 8, in <module>
    from http import client as httplib
ImportError: cannot import name 'client'
```

My Python version is 3.6.4. I tried to run code from 2.7.15, but it generated a different error earlier, so I will stick to 3.6.4.

Also, I've been getting one error earlier: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, but in file http.py I replaced:

```
from .compatibility import HTTPError, httplib
```

with:

```
from compatibility import HTTPError, httplib
```

and it works okay until current error.

I have never used Python before, but I failed trying to find a way to get API access in VBA and Python has an existing solution.

Comment: Can I know why down vote? Should I add some information or edit something?

Comment: It is expected that you post the error traceback as text.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will figure out how to do it and edit my post.

Comment: I think don't put myauth.py inside the packages folder and it will work. Maybe just try from your home directory to start with.

Comment: @Hitobat So simple and it worked! Please post it as an answer. It also explains the other error with .compatibility vs compatibility which in case of placing myAuth.py outside ...\site-packages\upwork\  folder works well in vanilla state, meaning with preceding dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, place the `myauth.py` script not inside the upwork package folder (e.g. just try user homedir).

The reason is, the site-packages/upwork folder defines the upwork package contents, so `import upwork` will not work from this location. In this way you are actually adding a `upwork.myauth` package.